# How to play streaming AV data in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to **play streaming AV data** from server **(ex. VLC server)**

Server send AV file data to client by TCP/IP.

Client get streaming data and queue buffers,
finally play AV in buffer queue.
(Before file download complete. It literally 'streaming')

Is there any APIs in iOS framework to do this?

Comment: I think AVPlayer is the one you're searching for.

Comment: Thank you  for your reply.  I have seen AVPlayer's document,  but It is not support 'buffer queue play' . (I should have wrote more detail :) )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it with AudioFileStream & AudioQueue Service.

AudioQueue support vary audio formats.

Please refer to Apple doc.

FYI.